# Python 'unresolved import keyboard'. PyInstaller

Tags: python, keyboard, pyinstaller

I have a simple python:

```
import requests
import keyboard
resp = requests.get('http://www.google.com')
keyboard.send('A')
```

This is an example.

When I run this code with `python main.py` everything is ok, but in VSCode the second line is underlined because "unresolved import 'keyboard' "
The first line is not underlined. Pyinstaller is the biggest problem. After generating the .exe file does not work because:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "keyboard"` Both modules are installed

Comment: sounds like you have two different versions of python - one in Visual studio and other launched by writing `python` to the command line

Comment: no problem, I decided to comment instead of answer because I have no idea how to check python interpreter in Visual Studio. I upvoted the Liam's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to configure VsCode to use the same interpreter as the one that the module is installed in, i'm not a VsCode advocate so I don't use it but I know it's possible.  This might help you out: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

> To select an specific environment, use the Python: Select Interpreter
>   command from the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P).